# Handling Concat and Shift Feature in Pandas for Data Science

Tags: python, neural-network, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to USE Lag features AND Concat() and Shift() function,

```
    seies = Series.from_csv('sugar_price_2.csv', header=0, sep=';')

    In [25]: prices = DataFrame(series.values)

    In [26]: dataframe = concat([prices.shift(3), prices.shift(2), prices.shift(1), prices], axis=1)

    In [27]: dataframe.coloumns = ['t-2', 't-1', 't', 't+1']

    In [28]: print(dataframe.head(20))

       0       0       0     0      
0      NaN     NaN     NaN  2800
1      NaN     NaN  2800.0  2800
2      NaN  2800.0  2800.0  2800
3   2800.0  2800.0  2800.0  2800
4   2800.0  2800.0  2800.0  2800
5   2800.0  2800.0  2800.0  2800
```

But The 't-2', 't-1', 't' Coloumn names aren't showing up .

Can anyone say what's wrong in my code...

Comment: It is spelled: `.columns`.

Comment: Might add the tag 'pandas' and post your questions on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by **@Stephan Rauch** in his comment, the names of the columns are stored in `dataframe.columns` - the OP had a typo.

Below is a working example with dummy data, getting the same output as the user - using instead a little loop to compute the shifted values.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

prices = dict(
    col1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    col2=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    col3=[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    col4=[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18])

dataframe = DataFrame.from_dict(prices)
print(dataframe)
new_col_names = ['t-2', 't-1', 't', 't+1']
dataframe.columns = new_col_names
print(dataframe)

# Number of columns we have
N = len(dataframe.columns)

for n, col in enumerate(dataframe.columns):
    shift_by = N - n - 1  # don't shift the final column
    dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].shift(periods=shift_by, axis=0)

print(dataframe)

# If desired, remove the new NaNs that appear in the first
final_dataframe = dataframe.drop(labels=dataframe.index[:N - 1], axis='index')
print(final_dataframe)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Does this Code reduces the time complexity ?

Comment: How can I Extract the Colomns from my dataset and put in like you did for prices = dict(......

Comment: @Arnab_AI - My code might be faster because it doesn't explicitly use  `concat`, which makes copies of its inputs. (Although the shift method itself [does copy data](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L7909))You can get columns from the dataframe by name. Make a list of the columns you want: `['col1', 'col2', 'col5']` - then select them like this: `subsetDF = datafame[cols_you_want]`. That returns a new dataframe with just the columns you want. If you want to turn that result into a dictionary, you can do `subset_as_dict = subsetDF.to_dict()`.

Comment: got it.. actually i have to shift the values for creating a unsupervised model  for a time series analysis , where the data set is only having date-time and price .... Thats why i had to use Shift and use those sifted columns as features